# Convolution of $e^{-a|x|} \ast e^{-a|x|}$ with $a>0$ using Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

This question is similar to [Convolution of $e^{-|x|} \ast e^{-|x|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628177/convolution-of-e-x-ast-e-x) but I'm looking to apply Fourier transform. Defining $f(x)=e^{-a|x|}$ with $a>0$, I know that $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{2a}{a^2 + 4\pi^2\xi^2}.$$

I can apply the property $\widehat{(f\ast f)} = \hat{f}.\hat{f} = (\hat{f})^2$. As such, using inverse Fourier transform, I can deduce that

$$e^{-a|x|} \ast e^{-a|x|} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\frac{2a}{a^2 + 4\pi^2\xi^2})^2 e^{2i\pi  x\xi} d\xi$$

Luckily, I covered a previous question where I established that the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\xi\mapsto\pi e^{-|\xi|}$, but it's still unclear to me how to apply this fact to the integral I have above.

Comment: Use "Feynman's trick", i.e. consider that your integrand (more or less) comes from a derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I(t,x)$ be given by the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(t,x)&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{t+k^2}e^{ikx }\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{t}|x|}}{2\sqrt{t}}
\end{align}$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ and setting $t=a^2$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\left.\left(\frac{\partial I(t,x)}{\partial t}\right)\right|_{t=a^2}&=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(a^2+k^2)^2}e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=-\frac{1+|ax|}{4|a|^3}\,e^{-|ax|}
\end{align}$$

Multiplying by $-4a^2$, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi \xi^2}\right)^2e^{i2\pi \xi x}\,d\xi=\frac{1+|ax|}{|a|}\,e^{-|ax|}$$

Comment: My thoughts have crossed yours...

Comment: @JeanMarie Do you mean the application of Feynman's trick?

Comment: Yes. Besides, I just found a related question [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h569721p3344322)

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived to define that integral $I(t,x)$? I mean, what gave you the intuition?

Comment: @ExerciseToTheReader Sure.  Feynman's trick is a fairly well-known methodology.